How do I make the yaxis ticks extend beyond the values in the chart
Basically all of my charts have values that extend beyond the axis in plotly. This includes line charts and bar charts. I can not find any resource for how to make this work in a logical way.
P.S. I am answering this question with my solution and just putting it here so that the next poor sole can find it.

Next time, you can check the "Answer your own question" box when composing a new question, so that you can both ask and answer the question in one submission.

Well that would have worked way better. Thanks for the tip.

This is the answer that I came up with. It is not pretty.
calculateAxis(data) {
  let [max, exponent] = Math.max(...data)
    .toExponential()
    .split('e')
  let maxRounded = Math.ceil(max)
  let step = 1
  if (maxRounded >= 8) {
    step = 2 * Math.pow(10, exponent)
    maxRounded = Math.ceil(maxRounded / 2) * 2
  } else if (maxRounded >= 5) {
    step = Math.pow(10, exponent)
  } else if (maxRounded > 1) {
    step = 0.5 * Math.pow(10, exponent)
  } else {
    step = 0.1 * Math.pow(10, exponent)
  }
  // need to determine the case when we have a step that would be on the way
  // e.g. max value is 2.2 and step is 0.5, but scale would go to 3
  let yLimit = maxRounded * Math.pow(10, exponent)
  if (yLimit - step > max * Math.pow(10, exponent)) {
    yLimit = yLimit - step
  }

  return [yLimit, step]
},

Then you just pop this into a yaxis in layout:
  let [yLimit, step] = this.calculateAxis(data[0].y)

  var layout = {
    title: 'some title',

    autosize: true,
    xaxis: {
      title: 'The X axis',
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: 'The y axis'
      },
      range: [0, yLimit],
      exponentformat: 'E',
    },
  }

  Plotly.newPlot('graphDiv', data, layout, config)

I hope this is helpful to somebody else.
